# Issue with node module timestampnotes "command not found"

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, npm, read-eval-print-loop

I am attempting to use an npm module named timestamp notes.

I have run the following

`$npm install timestampnotes`

`$timestamp`

and I get

`timestamp:126: command not found: slk`

i then tried opening a node repl

`$node`

`>var timestamp = require('timestampnotes');`

`>timestamp()`

and I get basically the same thing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a similar problem. If you are running with zsh on your terminal as opposed to bash, you need to set your 'Shells open with:' option in the Preferences>General to Command (complete path) and set the path to `/bin/zsh` [terminal Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUhMt.png)

The same needs to be done if you are running iTerm in place of your default Terminal. You can find this also in your Preferences>Profiles>General and again set Command to `/bin/zsh` [iTerm Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge3qG.png)

Comment: Okay, I should have mentioned I was using zsh. Now with that set it works both locally and globally. Thanks!